# Pass record id from !python to YAML in Odoo/OpenERP tests

Tags: python, testing, odoo, yaml

I have a record that is created in !python block by calling a function which creates Sale Orders from Crm Lead. Now I want to test a workflow on a new created Sale Order. Is there a way to pass id of a new sale_order back to YAML, so I will be able to use !workflow instruction?

Comment: If you post your code I can adapt my sample to Sale Orders, Crm Lead and the `!workflow` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the id to `ir.model.data` inside the `!python` block and it will be visible to the other blocks.

This is an example creating a group from a a python block and adding a user to it from a !record block:

```
-
  Create an external id 'test_group_id'
-                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  !python {model: res.groups}: |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    from openerp import SUPERUSER_ID                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    obj_id = self.create(cr, uid, {'name':'Test Group'}, context=context)                                                                                                                                                                      
    imd_values = {'module':'base', 'model': model._name, 'name': 'test_group_id', 'res_id': obj_id}                                                                                                                                            
    id = self.pool['ir.model.data'].create(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, imd_values, context=context)                                                                                                                                                      
    assert obj_id == ref('test_group_id'), 'saved reference should be equal'                                                                                                                                                                   
    assert id, 'external id should be saved'                                                                                                                                                                                                   
-
  The identifier 'test_group_id' should be visible from other "python" tags
-                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  !python {model: res.groups}: |
    assert ref('test_group_id'), 'External Id should exists' 
-
  Create user 'Test User' to include it in 'test_group_id'
-                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  !record {model: res.users, id: res_users_test, view: False}:
    company_id: base.main_company
    name: Test User
    login: testuser
    password: testuser
-
  Include the user in the referenced group. Then 'test_group_id' is visible from "record" tags.
-                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  !record {model: res.users, id: res_users_test}:
    groups_id:
      - base.test_group_id
```

Comment: I must add that this solution only works when the `external id` (`xml_id`) is unique for this test. The implementation of `process_record` in `yaml_import.py` uses `get_id` to resolve the references to external ids (with the alias `ref`). The `get_id` method looks first on a cache called `id_map` that can not be no accessed from the code of a `!python` tag. 
The environment variables that can be accessed from a !python tag are defined in the `code_context` dictionary of the `process_python` method.

Comment: I assume you want not to modify the yaml_import.py code otherwise you can include this in `code_context` from `process_python`: `{'yaml': self}` and extend my code with `yaml.id_map['test_group_id'] = id`